# Autostart+loop videos YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

YouTube recently discarded the old "embed" code and replaced it with iframe code.

In the new iframe code I found the way to loop+autostart videos on my website, thanks to [this article](http://brianwong.com/blog/2012-youtube-embed-code-autoplay-on-and-all-other-parameters/). It says:

> It's important to note that the “loop” parameter needs to work together
>   with the “playlist” parameter. This means that we are looping a
>   playlist that has only one video. So the embed code will look like
>   this:
>
> ```
> <iframe width=”560″ height=”315″ src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/V3oJR5IAMxM?rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=V3oJR5IAMxM” frameborder=”0″ allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```

But in my new code, why does each plalist have the two same videos?

When I apply the code the playlist, it has the same two videos in it. See for example:
[image: broken page screenshot]

How can I have only one video per playlist? I never created any playlists. YouTube shows by default that I have the same 2 videos in a playlist.

Answer (score 15):

This is the correct way to loop the videos of a playlist (as Google explains [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Selecting_Content_to_Play))

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?
    listType=playlist&
    list=PLAYLIST_ID&
    version=3&
    loop=1&
    autoplay=1&
    rel=0&
    showinfo=0&
    controls=0&
    autohide=1
" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 12):

I came here with a similar question. That question has been solved, heres how i did it.
Where you link the source, just get the original embed code, then replace the part that says embed with v.
**ex:**

```
www.youtube.com/v/lG5aSZBAuPs
```

**(embed was originally here, now its a v)**

Now add these attributes (or whatever the name for them would be) to the end of that embed link:

1. &autoplay=1
2. &loop=1
3. &playlist=lG5aSZBAuPs <-- this is the video  id shown at the end of the embed source link.

so at the end the link should look like so:

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/v/lG5aSZBAuPs&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=lG5aSZBAuPs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy the YouTube Embedded code then make these amendments.

- Change embed to v
- insert &autoplay=1
- insert &loop =1
- insert &playlist = "video-id"

This gives:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/v/agAX34aHvCM&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=agAX34aHvCM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There are so many people having trouble with this.....

Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the loop parameter requires the playlist param as well,  - I'm adding the note from YouTube's documentation.

Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:

Answer (score 0):

[SEE ALL OPTIONS descriptions CLICK here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

```html
autohide
autoplay
cc_load_policy
color
controls
disablekb
enablejsapi
end
fs
hl
iv_load_policy
list
listType
loop
modestbranding
origin
playerapiid
playlist
playsinline
rel
showinfo
start
theme
```

Answer (score 0):

use
playlist= you video embed
autoplay=1 
and loop=1

try this and see

```
<iframe style="height:600px;width:100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ithw-xIyd_8?playlist=ithw-xIyd_8&loop=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen" ></iframe>
```

it work powerful